# Socket.io specific port

Tags: c#, socket.io

I want to know if when you open a connection to a socket.io server by javascript,

```
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
</script>
```

The device needs to have some ports opened?

I'm asking this, because I need to create a only socket.io server to enable the connection between two clients: a web application and a Visual C# .Net. And I want to know if I need to enable some ports for the C# application.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If no URL is specified in the socket.io connection, then socket.io will use the host and port from the current web page that you are making the connection from.

If a URL is specified in the socket.io connection and no port is specified in that URL, socket.io will use the default port for that protocol so for `http://localhost`, the default port would be port 80.

So, yes port 80 must be open for outbound connections on the device originating the webSocket connection and must be open for inbound connections on localhost and, in fact, there must be a process listening to that port that can handle webSocket requests.  You may want to know that all webSocket requests start out as an http request that then goes through an "upgrade" process to switch from the http protocol to the webSocket protocol.